# More concise way to set object property where object might be null or undefined

Tags: javascript, coding-style, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript `errors` object that I'm using in a Salesforce Lightning Web Component on a out-of-box table component called a datatable. I won't go into all the details of how it's used, but for the purposes of my question, `errors` can be null, or it can have a `rows` property (which itself is an object, used for row-level errors), and also it can have a `table` property (also an object, used for table-level errors).

Here are some possible values of `errors`:

```
errors = null;

errors = {
    rows: {
        ...
    }
}

errors = {
    table: {
        ...
    }
}

errors = {
    rows: {
        ...
    },
    table: {
        ...
    }
}
```

When setting a table-level error, I don't want to just say `errors = { table: {...}}` because then I may be overriding some row-level errors. So here's how I'm currently coding it:

```
if (errors === null) {
    errors = { table: {} };
} else {
    errors.table = {};
}
errors.table.title = 'You must select at least one item to be returned.';
```

Is there a more concise way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an `else`:

```js
errors = errors || {};
errors.table = errors.table || {};
```

In modern JavaScript environments, it's better to use `??` (coalescing operator):

```js
errors = errors ?? {};
errors.table = errors.table ?? {};
```

And it can be even shorter:

```js
errors ??= {};
errors.table ??= {};
```

In your case there's not much difference, but `||` performs an old-school "truthy" test on the value, while `??` just checks for `null` and `undefined`.

Speaking of that, in *most* circumstances when comparing to `null`, I prefer to use `==` over `===` because with `==` both `null` and `undefined` are considered the same thing. It's somewhat fragile to explicitly distinguish between the two in most coding situations.